# No such a Column error

Tags: android, sqlite

is there anything wrong with this with the rawQuery, why after getting string from edit text to check in db alway crash... error No such Column : aaaa ... while compiling: SELECT * FROM....

```
public boolean isGotName(String Pname){
boolean result = false;

Cursor sName = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Pro_Name + "=" + Pname, null);

result = true;
int numberOfRows = sName.getCount();
if(numberOfRows <= 0)
{
   result = false;
    return result;
}
result = true;

return result;
}//isGOtId
```

and here

```
            Database dbc = new Database(this);
            dbc.open();
            String Pname = searchId.getText().toString();
                boolean checkName = dbc.isGotName(Pname);
            //  boolean checkName = true;
                if(checkName == true){
                    String s = searchId.getText().toString();
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("key",s);
                    b.putInt("keyX", radioBtnFlag);
                    Intent a = new Intent(SearchUpdate.this, UpdateDelete.class);
                    a.putExtras(b);
                    startActivity(a);

                    searchId.setText(null);
                }else{
                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("Error!");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("This Search is allow only ID!" + radioBtnFlag );
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();

                    searchId.setText(null);
                }
```

...

```
    db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " 
        +  Pro_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        +  Pro_Name + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
        +  Pro_Price + " Integer Not null, " 
        +  Pro_Description + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        +  Pro_Date + " TEXT NOT NULL ); "  );
```

Comment: Your error is pretty clear, you should check your DB structure to see if the column "aaaa" is here or not, seems not.

Comment: u mean the data in db? it have that aaaa...

Comment: What is `Pro_Name` set to? Also can u post table creation query?

Comment: db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " 
   +  Pro_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY                    AUTOINCREMENT, "
   +  Pro_Name + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
   +  Pro_Price + " Integer Not null, " 
   +  Pro_Description + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
   +  Pro_Date + " TEXT NOT NULL ); "  );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Cursor sName = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Pro_Name + "= '"+ Pname +"'", null);
```